# Printing DB2 Query Results to JSP from Java Servlet

Tags: jsp, jstl

the response.jsp in my dynamic web project is not displaying the results from database. Below is my code part and the connections are established without any issues

**OrderController.java**

```
package com.whs.reporting.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.waitrose.reporting.dao.OrderDao;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class OrderC
 */
@WebServlet(name="OrderServlet",urlPatterns={"/OrderController"})
public class OrderController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public OrderController() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        OrderDao dao = new OrderDao();
        try {           
            request.setAttribute("orders",dao.getallorders());          
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("Response.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);        
    }
}
```

**Response.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=EUC-KR" pageEncoding="EUC-KR"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=EUC-KR">
<title>Show Order Result</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table border=1>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Order Number</th>
                <th>Service Type</th>                
                <th>Delivery Date</th> 
                <th>Branch Number</th>               
                <th>Total</th>               
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <c:forEach items="${orders}" var="order">
                <tr>
                    <td>${order.ordernumber}</td>
                    <td>${order.service}</td>
                    <td>${order.deliverydate}</td>
                    <td>${order.branch}</td>
                    <td>${order.total}</td>                    
                </tr>
          </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone please let me know what i am missing here and why the jsp is not displaying the db results ?

Comment: You should only post the most relevant code you are facing issue with, unless someone explicitly asks to see more code.

Comment: Did you check that you are not having any exceptions generated by your code?

Comment: Thanks , i updated the question with the servelet and response.jsp and i am not having any exceptions in the generated code

Comment: @ChimbuDurai did below answer solved your problem?

Comment: I have added the tag but getting the error "javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTag" i have also added jstl.jar in the web app libraries.but still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include below Link in your `response.jsp`

```
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml" %>
```

Because you are using tag library, you need to provide it in jsp which is using tags of jstl.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=EUC-KR" 
pageEncoding="EUC-KR"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml" %>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=EUC-KR">
<title>Show Order Result</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border=1>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Order Number</th>
            <th>Service Type</th>                
            <th>Delivery Date</th> 
            <th>Branch Number</th>               
            <th>Total</th>               
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <c:forEach items="${orders}" var="order">
            <tr>
                <td>${order.ordernumber}</td>
                <td>${order.service}</td>
                <td>${order.deliverydate}</td>
                <td>${order.branch}</td>
                <td>${order.total}</td>                    
            </tr>
      </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[this can be help ful for reference](http://www.journaldev.com/2090/jstl-tutorial-jstl-example-jstl-core-tags)

Comment: I have added the tag but getting the error "javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTag" i have also added jstl.jar in the web app libraries.but still not working –

Comment: @ChimbuDurai try cleaning and redeploy in your tomcat or try below [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19731101/2749470) and this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21678762/2749470)

Comment: Added jstl-1.2.jar and it worked now. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @ChimbuDurai great then upvote this answer and accept this as working answer :) using green tick. Happy to help you.